# Upgraded From Angular 9 to 14 - build:ssr leads to Module parse failed error

Tags: angular, angular-universal

We have decided to update our Angular from 9, step-wise, to 14. after many updates to dependencies, I have been able to transpile the application just fine and run it locally via `ng serve` and even build it via `npm run build`. But when I try to make an ssr build, I'm met with this error after `Server application bundle generation complete`. I'm not quite sure what the issue is here based on the error message. The interesting part is, when I move that line of code somewhere else, the error text would just go down to the next line as if that is causing the error.

```
./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/app.scss:22:0 - 
Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (22:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   Animation
| *****/
> @keyframes slideRight {
|   from {
|     margin-left: 100%;


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appname-frontend@0.0.0 build:ssr: `node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --base-href / && npm run post-build && node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run appname-frontend:server:production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the appname-frontend@0.0.0 build:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacobjohn/.npm/_logs/2022-08-26T20_13_00_889Z-debug.log
```

Here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "start-test": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run appname-frontend:serve-coverage",
    "start-lighthouse": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve -c test",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --base-href /app/ && npm run post-build",
    "test": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test",
    "test:tc": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --watch=false --source-map=false --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "e2e:ci": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run appname-frontend-e2e:e2e-ci",
    "e2e:coverage": "npx nyc report --reporter=lcov --reporter=text-summary",
    "serve-coverage": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run appname-frontend:serve-coverage",
    "ngcc": "ngcc",
    "lighthouse:ci": "lhci autorun",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "cypress:browserstack:start": "browserstack-cypress run",
    "cypress:open": "./node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress open",
    "cypress:r": "node run-cypress.js",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run --record --key 6178512f-732c-46dc-9b45-db19c83f5792",
    "cypress:ci": "run-p --race start-test cypress:r",
    "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit",
    "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
    "post-build": "node ./build/post-build.js",
    "build:ssr_bak": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run post-build && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr_bak": "node dist/server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles_bak": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --base-href /app/ && node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run appname-frontend:server",
    "dev:ssr": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run appname-frontend:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --base-href / && npm run post-build && node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run appname-frontend:server:production",
    "prerender": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run appname-frontend:prerender",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "deploy": "docker-compose up --build || true",
    "compodoc": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@compodoc/compodoc/bin/index-cli.js -p tsconfig.json"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 0.5%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "Firefox ESR",
    "not dead",
    "not IE 9-11"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.19.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "14.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^14.1.3",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullstory/browser": "^1.4.5",
    "@gorniv/ngx-universal": "^2.2.2",
    "@highcharts/map-collection": "^1.1.3",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.0-rc.1.20451.17",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13",
    "@ng-matero/extensions": "^14.1.0",
    "@ngrx/data": "^14",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^14",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^14",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^14",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^14",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@sentry/angular": "^7.11.1",
    "@sentry/fullstory": "^1.1.5",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.16.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-base": "^20.2.45",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^20.2.45",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^20.2.45",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids": "^20.2.45",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "^20.2.45",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-lists": "^20.2.45",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations": "^20.2.45",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-querybuilder": "^20.2.45",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "^2.2.2",
    "@types/numeral": "0.0.26",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.5",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.25",
    "@uirouter/angular": "^9.1.0",
    "@uirouter/core": "^6.0.6",
    "@uirouter/rx": "^0.6.5",
    "angular": "^1.8.1",
    "angular-file": "2.0.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "^8.5.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.2",
    "highcharts": "^8.2.0",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.4",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.7",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "launchdarkly-js-client-sdk": "^2.19.2",
    "less": "^3.12.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "log4js": "^3.0.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nanoscroller": "0.8.7",
    "ng-editable-table": "^0.3.15",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^13.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-loggly-logger": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^4.2.1",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.3.0",
    "ngx-window-token": "^5.0.0",
    "npm": "^8.1.3",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "sass": "^1.54.4",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "terraformer-wkt-parser": "^1.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "8.0.14",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-loggly-bulk": "^2.0.3",
    "xstate": "^4.13.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "9.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.1.3",
    "@briebug/cypress-schematic": "^4.3.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.18",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.9.2",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.5.0",
    "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "^1.0.1",
    "@lhci/cli": "^0.9.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^14",
    "@types/angular": "^1.7.3",
    "@types/angular-ui-router": "^1.1.37",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/d3": "^5.16.4",
    "@types/d3-geo": "^1.12.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.7",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.44",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.64",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.7",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cypress": "^6.9.1",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.4.0",
    "cypress-social-logins": "^1.6.0",
    "electron": "^8.5.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "1.2.4",
    "gulp-rename": "1.3.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "3.0.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "istanbul-lib-coverage": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-teamcity-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "ng-mocks": "^14.1.3",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^11.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0",
    "regexp-replace-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.11.5",
    "ts-loader": "8.0.14",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4",
    "wallaby-webpack": "3.9.9",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

Here is the angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "appname-frontend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.png",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/min"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng-omega-theme.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
              {
                "input": "src/custom-theme.scss",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles2.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/app.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
              "../../libs/react-component/main.min.js"
            ],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "coverage": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appname-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "appname-frontend:build:production"
            },
            "test": {
              "browserTarget": "appname-frontend:build:test"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-coverage": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appname-frontend:build:coverage",
            "extraWebpackConfig": "./cypress/coverage.webpack.js"
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "build-dev": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.png",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/min/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng-omega-theme.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
              {
                "input": "src/custom-theme.scss",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles2.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/app.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
              "../../libs/react-component/main.min.js"
            ],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "coverage": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appname-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
              "../../libs/react-component/main.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng-omega-theme.css",
              "src/assets/theme/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
              {
                "input": "src/custom-theme.scss",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles2.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/app.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.png",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco",
                "output": "./assets/monaco/min/"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appname-frontend:build",
            "serverTarget": "appname-frontend:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "appname-frontend:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "appname-frontend:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "appname-frontend:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "appname-frontend:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {},
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-run": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-open": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend:serve",
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "appname-frontend-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend:serve-coverage",
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend:serve-coverage:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "e2e-ci": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "browser": "chrome",
            "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend:serve-coverage",
            "headless": true,
            "watch": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend:serve-coverage:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-run": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend-e2e:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend-e2e:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "cypress-open": {
          "builder": "@briebug/cypress-schematic:cypress",
          "options": {
            "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend-e2e:serve",
            "watch": true,
            "headless": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "appname-frontend-e2e:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": ""
    }
  }
}
```

here is my app.server.json file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FlexLayoutServerModule} from '@angular/flex-layout/server';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    FlexLayoutServerModule,
],
  providers: [
    // Add universal-only providers here
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having similar issues, I figured out the fix.

I decided to created a brand new angular 14 app and checked the version difference and noticed my angular builder was a few major versions behind so I updated this. The error message remained but was more descriptive and noticed that there was a css-loader trying to load app.scss in app.ts file. I removed this line of code and it started to build correctly.